# What is wrong with this many-to-many relationship in EF code-first?

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-first, relationship

I have these schema in my database:

```
Tb1: { Id:int , NameTb1:varchar(50) }
Tb2: { Id:int , NameTb2:varchar(50) }
Tb1Tb2 { Tb1Id:int , Tb2Id:int }
```

Obviously `Tb1Tb2` is a relationship table and I want to define a many-to-many relationship in EF code-first.

And these are the entity classes :

```
public class Tb1 
{
   public Tb1()
   {
       ListTb2 = new List<Tb2>();
   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string NameTb1 { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Tb2> ListTb2 { get; set; }
}

public class Tb2 
{
   public Tb2()
   {
       ListTb1 = new List<Tb1>();
   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string NameTb2 { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Tb1> ListTb1 { get; set; }
}
```

and mappings :

```
 public class Tb1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tb1>
 {
    public Tb1Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        this.HasMany(x => x.ListTb2)
            .WithMany(xx => xx.ListTb1)
            .Map
            (
                x =>
                    {
                        x.MapLeftKey("Tb1Id");
                        x.MapRightKey("Tb2Id");
                        x.ToTable("Tb1Tb2");
                    }
            );     
    }
}

public class Tb2Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tb2>
{
    public Tb2Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

When I use it in my app :

```
var sv1 = new TableService<Tb1>(_uow);
var sv2 = new TableService<Tb2>(_uow);

var t1 = new Tb1 { NameTb1 = "T111" };
sv1.Add(t1);
//var res1= _uow.SaveChanges();

var t2 = new Tb2 { NameTb2 = "T222" };
sv2.Add(t2);
//var res2 = _uow.SaveChanges();

t1.ListTb2.Add(t2);
var result = _uow.SaveChanges();
```

I get this error:

> *An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.*

and inner exception is:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Tb1Tb2_Tb2". The conflict occurred in database "dbTest", table
>   "dbo.Tb2", column 'Id'.*

Why do I get this error?
and what is the solution?
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the

```
sv2.Add(t2);
```

and it worked